# How to calculate MTD in NRF 4-5-4 calendar using current day

Tags: sql, date, calendar, range, date-range

I am wondering how to write logic to calculate MTD in nrf 454 calendar. Normally MTD is pretty simple, if today is 03.09.2020 then MTD: from 01.09.2020 to 03.09.2020, so it is a date range from first day of the current month to the current day.

The problem is that nrf 454 calendar seems to be all over the place and I can't find any pattern I could use to create this logic without writing a ton of if/case statements.

Here is an example of nrf 454 calendar: [image: nrf 454 calendar example]

I am also pretty limited on technologies because I can't really use any libraries. What I can use is
SQL and plain javascript.

So I am looking for a logic behind those calendars which I could replicate in order to get MTD date ranges based on the current day, so something like a function that takes a day as parameter and returns MTD. I don't want to hardcode it using a ton of ifs unless someone already has done it for years 2018-2022

Answer (score 0):

Rules are prety simple actualy.. here they are:

// 4 weeks have 28 days
// 5 weeks have 35 days

// 1 one month will have or either 4 weeks or either 5 weeks
// 454 445 544 are 3 months sequence, one quarters  always have 35 + 28 + 28 = 91 days
// Semesters always have 182 days
// One year always have 364 days

// Because years have 365 days, there are 1 day or 2 remaining each year
// 1 day in regular years, 2 days in leap years.

// Every years that remaining days reaches 7 days, there's a need to add an extra week (53 weeks year)

// Leap years are those who can be divided by 4 and 400 but not by 100.

// One fiscal calendar can start in any gregorian date. first day of the week of such calendar will always be the very first date

If you loop counters between each bounds, for time unit, weeks, months, quarter, semesters year ( placing months according an progression array ) you only needs to IF's.. One for months progression, another for leap years.

I'm doing an implementation myself, i hope i have it in a while

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to format code.